# Solving initial value problem with separation of variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to find the solution $\lambda(x)$ to the problem $$y'(x)=\frac{1}{1+3y(x)^2},$$ with $ y(0)=0$, using separation of variables.

$\qquad \ \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{1+3y(x)^2}$
$\iff \frac{dy}{dx}(1+3y(x)^2)=1$
$\iff \int 1+3y(x)^2 dy=\int dx$
$\iff y(x) + y(x)^3 = x + c$,$\quad$ where $c$ is an arbitrary constant
Using $y(0)=0$, we get that $y(0) + y(0)^3 = 0 + c \iff c=0$
Therefore: $y(x) + y(x)^3 = x$

At this point I am stuck, how do I find the solution $\lambda(x)$, as I am also interested in finding the limits $\lim_{x\to\infty}\lambda(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to-\infty}\lambda(x)$ ? Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Now, solve the cubic equation $y^3+y-x=0$ for $y$. Quite simple since you already made all the work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now set $y=a(v-v^{-1})$ to get
$$
a(v-v^{-1})+a^3(v^3-v^{-3}-3(v+v^{-1}))=x
$$
Fix the freedom of the parametrization by demanding $3a^2=1$ so that you are left with
$$
\frac{v^3-v^{-3}}2=\frac{\sqrt{27}}2x
$$
which you now can solve using the hyperbolic sine function,
$$
v=e^u\implies \sinh(3u)=\frac{\sqrt{27}}2x, ~~ y=\frac{2}{\sqrt3}\sinh(u).
$$

---

For the qualitative properties you should just argue from the property that $y\mapsto y+y^3$ is a strictly monotonously increasing function.

Comment: Don't you think that it could be simpler to solve the cubic with the hyperbolic method directly ? Cheers :-)

Comment: Yes, of course, if you have memorized this trick with the necessary factors, or have it on an easily accessible cheat sheet...

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thanks for your answer! I might be doing something wrong but with $y(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}*sinh(x)$ I am not getting $y^3+y=x$

Comment: You have replaced $u$ with $x$. Combined you should get $$y=\frac{2}{\sqrt3}\sinh\left(\frac13\sinh^{-1}\left(3\frac{\sqrt3}2x\right)\right).$$